# Letterpress in WPF

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

How can I achieve the letterpress effect on a text in .NET WPF?

Comment: You might want to link to an example image of the effect you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bevel bitmapeffect on your text and container. A combination can achieve the letter press effect.